# What is the least nonnegative number $a$ congruent to $3^{340}\pmod{341}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Find the least nonnegative number $a$ congruent to $3^{340} \pmod{341}$.

---

What steps should I take to get to the answer?

Comment: Is 341 a prime?

Comment: 56. There, found it!

Comment: No it's not....

Comment: $341=11\cdot 31$

Answer (score 4):

As $341=11\cdot31,$

Using [Fermat's Little Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatsLittleTheorem.html), $ 3^{10}\equiv1 \pmod {11}$

$\implies 3^{340}=(3^{10})^{34}\equiv1^{34}\equiv1\pmod{11}\ \ \ \ (1)$

Again applying  Fermat's Little Theorem, $3^{30}\equiv1\pmod {31}$

$\implies 3^{340}=(3^{30})^{11}\cdot 3^{10}\equiv 1\cdot3^{10}\equiv 3^{10} \pmod {31}$

Now, $3^3\equiv-4\pmod {31}\implies 3^{10}=3\cdot (3^3)^3\equiv3\cdot (-4)^3\equiv 3(-2)\equiv-6$

$\implies 3^{340}\equiv-6\ \ \ \ (2)$

Now, use [CRT](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html) in $(1),(2)$ to find $x\equiv56\pmod{341}$

Comment: Without using CRT, we can start with $11a+1=x=31a-6$ for some integer $a,b$

$$\implies 11a+7=31b\implies 11(a-5)=31(b-2)$$
$$\implies \frac{11(a-5)}{31}=b-2\text{ which is an integer}$$

$$\implies  31|11(a-5)\implies  31|(a-5)\text{  as }(31,11)=1$$

So, $a=31c+5,\implies x=11a+7=11(31c+5)+1=341c+56$

Answer (score 1):

mod $\,11\!:\ 3^{340}\! \equiv (3^{10})^{34} \equiv 1^{34}\! \equiv 1\ $ by little Fermat. $ $ Similarly

mod $\,31\!:\ 3^{340}\! \equiv 3^{10} (3^{30})^{10}\! \equiv (3^5)^2 1^{10}\! \equiv (9(9\cdot 3)))^2\! \equiv (9(-4))^2\!\equiv (-5)^2\! \equiv \color{#0a0}{25}$

By CRT, $ $ mod $\,11\!:\ 1 \equiv 3^{340}\! = \color{#0a0}{25}+31k \equiv 3-2k,\,$ so $\, 3k\equiv 3,\,$ so $\,\color{#c00}{k\equiv 1}.\,$

Therefore $\, 3^{340}\! = 25\!+\!31\color{#c00}k = 25\!+\!31(\color{#c00}1\!+\!11n) = 56\! +\! 340n$.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Carmichael function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function), $\lambda(341)=$lcm$(\phi(11),\phi(31))=$lcm$(10,30)=10$

$\displaystyle \implies 3^{30}\equiv1\pmod{341}$ and as $340\equiv10\pmod{30}$

$\displaystyle \implies 3^{340}\equiv3^{10}\pmod{341}$

Now, $\displaystyle3^5=243\equiv-98,3^6\equiv-98\cdot3\equiv47,3^7\equiv49\cdot3=141\pmod{341}$

$\displaystyle3^8\equiv141\cdot3=423\equiv82,3^9\equiv82\cdot3=246\equiv-95\pmod{341}$

$\displaystyle\implies 3^{10}\equiv3\cdot(-9)=-285\equiv56\pmod{341}$